# What do these labels in SourceTree mean?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm beginning to try our SourceTree for managing my git repositories.

For the life of me I don't understand the labeling system that they use on the branches. It seems to me that there are more than I'm expexing and it's unclear on how I should read these.

I've looked online at Atlassian.com, and sourcetreeapp.com but they don't seem to have any documentation on the SourceTree product.

Can anyone help my understand the origin/master, origin/develop, master, and develop labels that appear on the same node?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Those labels represent the:

- local branches (blue)
- remote tracking branches (gray)

The latter one are created when you fetch a remote repo, in order for your local repo to remember what was most recently fetched.

In your case, the local branches master and develop reference the same SHA1 as the remote tracking branches: your local and remote repo are in sync.

You can see that same label system in the [Atlassian `git fetch` tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/#!fetch):

[image: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch]